# I need to input the friction factor from the Approximations of the Colebrook equation in python

Tags: python, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to code an approximation of the Colebrook equation to obtain the friction factor. I have achieved this in Matlab but when it come to python my code does not work.

```py
import math
Re = 2300
eD=0.0009 
1/math.sqrt(friction)=-2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))
print(friction)
```

I also tried this

```py
import math
def friction(Re, eD):
    eD= 0.0009
    Re= 2300
    f = -2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))
    return 1/math.sqrt(f)
```

but this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of the Colebrook equation, but assuming the formula in this line:

```
1/math.sqrt(friction)=-2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))
```

is correct, we can just rearrange to

```
import math
Re = 2300
eD = 0.0009 
friction = (1/(-2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))))**2
print(friction)
```

Giving us

```
friction = 0.05073525684035217
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the value (and not trying to demonstrate that you can solve it yourself) a python module already exists, see: [colebrook](https://pypi.org/project/colebrook/)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approximations of the Colebrook equation. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae) Which one are you referring to? It helps to know what you are trying to do more specifically.

Aside from that, there is an easy issue here.

```
1/math.sqrt(friction)=-2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))
```

In Python (and most languages I've ever used), you can't write equations this way. The computer will not solve algebra for you. If you solve to get `f=SomeEquation()`, only then can the computer actually do the math for you.

In your second example there are also issues.

```
import math
def friction(Re, eD):
    eD= 0.0009
    Re= 2300
    f = -2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))
    return 1/math.sqrt(f)
```

You have defined a function which takes `Re` and `eD`, but then you immediately redefine them in thee function. There is a way to set a default value for these variables if you choose not to pass them in, but I don't think that's what you are trying to do here. Furthermore, (and you may very well have just left this part out for the sake of brevity) you never actually ***called*** your function, which means your script never actually does anything.

You need something like (and I'm not checking your equation here because I don't know which one you were going for):

```
import math

# Function definition
def friction(Re, eD):
    f = -2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))
    return 1/math.sqrt(f)

# Call your function with your desired values (arguments) and store the result in f
f = friction(2300, 0.0009)
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
Re = 2300
eD = 0.0009 
friction = (1/(-2*math.log10((((eD/3.7)+(2.51/Re))*(1.14-2*math.log10(((eD/2)+(21.25/Re**0.9))))))))**2
print(friction)

Output: 0.05073525684035217

import colebrook
Re = 2300
eD = 0.0009 
factor = colebrook.sjFriction( Re, eD)
print(factor)

Output: 0.0495
```

For further help you could visit https://pypi.org/project/colebrook/